# Windows 8 screen turn off and doesn't turn on when in activity

Tags: windows-8, sleep, hibernate

I've just bought my laptop with windows 8 64-bits pre-installed.
The laptop is fast, and the operating system works (almost) perfectly.

What is happening is that if I stop using the laptop for a while (like 2 minutes), the screen turn off, and even after moving mouse, pressing keys or clicking, the screen doesn't turn on again.

(Yes, I have already changed the power settings to avoid the laptop from entering in sleep mode)

I stop using it, and the screen turn off (It really turn off, not with black pixels alight). When I use it again, the screen alight the screen entirely black, only black pixels alight.
when this happen to me, the unique solution I have found so far, is to put the computer in sleep mode, and then make it awake... After this, it continues running perfectly.

Reading some websites, I found a suggestion about using a command to deactivate the hibernate mode: `powercfg -h off`
What supposedly deactivate the hibernate mode and forces the Kernel to reload from the begining each time, making the boot slower.

I have already downloaded and installed the newest driver for my graphics card compatible with windows 8.
GeForce GTX 670MX

Any suggestion?